# PHP AWS SDK throwing unknown error

Tags: php, curl, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have been working with amazon S3 for media storage for a e-commerce site but I ran into this error and have no idea how to fix it:

```
Use of undefined constant CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST - assumed 'CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST'
```

Its coming from CurlBackoffStrategy witch is, as the [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php-2/latest/class-Guzzle.Plugin.Backoff.CurlBackoffStrategy.html) states:

> Strategy used to retry when certain cURL error codes are encountered.

I'm assuming this is software incompatibility some were but I'm no sure where to look.

This code dose work on my local test environment but when the server gets it, it just fails.
I have updated PHP and, curl to the same as my test environment but to no avail.

If anyone has any idea on what this error message means or a direction to point me in would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which version of php/curl are you using? Your local environment may be not showing this error as I believe its of the E_NOTICE level.

Comment: It's strange that you'd get this error. CURLE_COULDNT_RESOLVE_HOST is a valid cURL constant that has been around since well before PHP 5.3 (looks like it's been in cURL [since 2004](https://github.com/bagder/curl/commit/8f77030473abafff1ccd44b095ce94fcd4a96dab#L0R47)). Check your curl version and version of PHP. Are you building PHP and curl from source for some reason? Are you able to use other cURL error codes like CURLE_COULDNT_CONNECT  correctly?

Comment: curl 7.22.0 php 5.4.14-1 are the versions I'm using.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I had forgotten to install php5-curl on my server.